# List all snapshots for a storage account using Azure Java SDK or REST API

Tags: java, rest, azure, azure-java-sdk

I need to list all snapshots for each blob in Azure, using the Java SDK if possible or the Azure REST API otherwise. For both options, I know how to list all storage accounts, but I have not found a way to retrieve a list of snapshots associated with a single storage account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to the [javadocs](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/) of Azure Storage SDK for Java, using the method [`listBlobs(String prefix, boolean useFlatBlobListing, EnumSet<BlobListingDetails> listingDetails, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext opContext)`](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlobContainer.html#listBlobs(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.util.EnumSet,%20com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobRequestOptions,%20com.microsoft.azure.storage.OperationContext)) with [`BlobListingDetails.SNAPSHOTS`](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobListingDetails.html#SNAPSHOTS) for a container to list all blobs which include `snapshot blob` to filter by the method `isSnapshot()`.

Here is my sample code below.

```
String accountName = "<your-storage-account-name>";
String accountKey = "<your-storage-account-key>";
String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=%s;AccountKey=%s";
String connectionString = String.format(storageConnectionString, accountName, accountKey);
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
// List all containers of a storage account
Iterable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = client.listContainers();
String prefix = null;
boolean useFlatBlobListing = true;
// Specify the blob list which include snapshot blob
EnumSet<BlobListingDetails> listingDetails = EnumSet.of(BlobListingDetails.SNAPSHOTS);
BlobRequestOptions options = null;
OperationContext opContext = null;
for (CloudBlobContainer container : containers) {
    Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobItems = container.listBlobs(prefix, useFlatBlobListing, listingDetails, options,
                    opContext);
    for (ListBlobItem blobItem : blobItems) {
        if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
            CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItem;
            // Check a blob whether be a snapshot blob
            if (blob.isSnapshot()) {
                System.out.println(blobItem.getStorageUri());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use REST API for implementing this needs, the steps as below.

1. Using [`List Containers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-containers2) for a storage account to list all containers.
2. Using [`List Blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-blobs) with the url parameter `include={snapshots}` as the subsection `Blob and Snapshot List` of the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/enumerating-blob-resources#a-namesubheading5a-xml-response-format) said to list all blobs of a container which include snapshot blob, then to filter all snapshot blobs.